# How To find handle to process created by system

Tags: winapi

Firstly i want to appologize about my english it's a bit rusty.

I have two applications. First one (A) is main app which is created by 'SYSTEM' sheduler with maximal user privileges. Second one (B) is created by logged user.

Application B SendMessage(WM_COPYDATA) to application A and in result recieve a char of Application B state and display it. When both applications are running by user everything is fine. But when Application B is run under SYSTEM user i can't find a handle to this app.

My question is: How to find a handle to application A when is running as 'SYSTEM' ?

Comment: This isn't going to work. This breaks the security model. You'll likely need to find another IPC mechanism, e.g. named pipes, and secure them to permit communication at different privilege levels.

Comment: OK. Thanks. It's like i think, but wan't to make sure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the security model would not prevent app B from *finding* app A's HWND (lower-privilege processes have read-only access to higher-privilege HWNDs). So I suspect the OP's code is simply searching for the HWND the wrong way, but he did not show his code. However, UIPI would block the `WM_COPYDATA` message, unless app A calls `ChangeWindowMessageFilter/Ex()` to allow the message. But you are right in that better IPC mechanisms do exist than using `WM_COPYDATA`.